# numpy multiply vectors to form square matrix

Tags: numpy

suppose I have two numpy arrays `x` and `y` of shape `N` which I want to represent as size `N x 1` each, and I want to multiply them as `x y'` to a get a matrix of size `N x N`. But if I try:

`np.dot(x, y.T)` or `np.dot(x.T, y)`

I always get a scalar (size `1 x 1`).

Is it possible to specify to numpy to multiply two arrays along a particular dimension?

To clarify, suppose I have

```
x = [x1, x2] 
y = [y1, y2]
```

I want

```
xy' = [[x1*y1, x1*y2], [x2*y1, x2*y2]]
```

but numpy always seems to return

```
xy' = x1*y1+x2*y2
```

Comment: Try `np.outer(x, y)`.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: if you put this as an answer, I can select it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `np.outer(x, y)`. You can also do it with broadcasting:

```
x[:, None] * y
```

which is more flexible